# Automatically break up long words inside DIV container but prefer line breaking on spaces

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, word-break, css-hyphens

I have a some kind of smaller side container, `#sideNavContainer`, in a parent div, on the other side (to the right) is another div for the content.

When I put text into the `#sideNavContainer` that contains very long words without spaces, the words begin to break out of the container and overwrite stuff on the right side (content area).

I tried to force the content of the `#sideNavContainer` to break up those words, so that they continue on the next line, when they reach the right end of the container but I am not 100% satisfied as I expected that the words/sentences should also be broken on spaces preferably. Long words should start on the next line and then be broken down and not begin on the same line as the other text (after a space) and then continue (but be broken).

Here is some example to hopefully illustrate what I mean:

```
<div>
  <div id="sideNavBox">
    <span>Navigation and other Stuff</span>
    <div id="subContainer">
      I am a very long Text andIevenContainVeryLongWordsWithout spaces but my parent container(s) should not ChangeTheirWidthBecauseOfThis and break whenThereAreSpaces but longWordsWithoutSpaces shouldBeBrokenDown.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="contentBox">
    Hello, I am the main content
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: green;
}

#sideNavBox {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#subContainer {
  background-color: grey;
  word-break: break-all;
}
#contentBox {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qp74uxkt/11/

My desire/expectation was that the text would break after the words "I am a very long Text", then on the next line continue with "andIevenContain..." and this long word then can be broken at the end of the available space, based on the restrictions of the parent container. This also does not work when I use "hyphens: auto;". Can this even be done?
[image: Example]

Comment: could be misunderstanding the question but does setting word-break: break-word; get you close to the desired outcome?

Comment: @digital-pollution yes, according to the fiddle this seems to work... in Chrome it looks like I expect it. But there seems also be a catch. I develop in IE 11 (for SharePoint), and there "break-word" seems not to be supported. There seems to be another CSS property "word-wrap: break-word" which is supported - but it does not alter the result. Is there a way to make it work in IE 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set word-break property as break-word. I have updated your code and created a new fiddle. I think it will solve your problem
`Check it out` https://jsfiddle.net/yvLb6zer/

Comment: I will accept this as answer, as it is correct - even when IE 11 cannot understand this CSS rule, but that is an issue with the browser.

Comment: Yes IE doesn't support this feature. IE doesn't support many CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of long words is not too large, I would recommend *not*  to use any `word-break` setting, but instead insert "soft hyphens" into these long word, at positions where it's grammatically correct.

A soft hyphen is an entity that looks like this: `&shy;`. So if you have for example `whateverwonderfullongword`, you could change that to `what&shy;ever&shy;wonder&shy;ful&shy;long&shy;word`. If it fits into the width, it will be written as a whole, if not, if not, it will break (with a hyphen) at the latest possible position of a `&shy;` entity, like in the following example.

```html
<p>what&shy;ever&shy;wonder&shy;ful&shy;long&shy;word what&shy;ever&shy;wonder&shy;ful&shy;long&shy;word what&shy;ever&shy;wonder&shy;ful&shy;long&shy;word what&shy;ever&shy;wonder&shy;ful&shy;long&shy;word what&shy;ever&shy;wonder&shy;ful&shy;long&shy;word what&shy;ever&shy;wonder&shy;ful&shy;long&shy;word what&shy;ever&shy;wonder&shy;ful&shy;long&shy;word what&shy;ever&shy;wonder&shy;ful&shy;long&shy;word</p>
```

Comment: But the content is user generated. I cannot add those soft hyphens myself on-the-fly.

Comment: oh, okay, in this case that won't help, sorry.